# Poco::Zip set Extension List

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

After successfully compress the zip file, I want to add extensions list in order to only zip any files that have extensions within the Extensions List.

```
set <string> extensionsSet;
std::ofstream fos(target, ios::binary);
Poco::Zip::Compress c(fos, true);
extensionsSet.insert("txt");
c.setStoreExtensions(extensionsSet);//set extensions List 

set <string> a = c.getStoreExtensions();//a contains 1 string which is txt

Poco::File aFile(source);
if (aFile.exists())
{
    if (aFile.isDirectory())
    {
        Poco::Path sourceDir(source);
        sourceDir.makeDirectory();
        c.addRecursive(sourceDir, Poco::Zip::ZipCommon::CompressionMethod::CM_DEFLATE,
            Poco::Zip::ZipCommon::CL_NORMAL, false);
    }
    else if (aFile.isFile())
    {
        Poco::Path p(aFile.path());
        c.addFile(p, p.getFileName(), Poco::Zip::ZipCommon::CompressionMethod::CM_AUTO,
            Poco::Zip::ZipCommon::CL_NORMAL);
    }
}
else {
    _log.EndMethod();
    throw new FileNotFoundException("File Not Found");
}


c.close(); // MUST be done to finalize the Zip file
fos.close();
```

Can anyone help me to find out what's wrong within my code, because I don't see any difference when I set the extensions List? I want to zip a file(e.g test.txt), following my code should "test.txt" be included in the zip file?

Comment: That's not what [`setStoreExtensions`](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Zip.Compress.html#32384) does.  If you want to only include files with a specific set of extensions in your archive you'll need to implement that logic yourself.

Comment: @MilesBudnek oh that helps a lot, so what `setStoreExtensions` actually does if you can tell?

Comment: As the documentation I linked says, it tells the library what file types not to compress when added to the archive with the `CM_AUTO` compression method.  It exists to avoid double-compressing files that are already in a compressed format since doing so will often result in a _larger_ file.

Comment: @MilesBudnek so it's apposite with what I need ,isn't it?? Because I compress using methods `AddRecursive` so if I want to implement my logic I have to change it right?

Comment: @MilesBudnek I just edited my post, after I add `txt` into the extension List nothing changes. I want to compress 1 txt file, the result must be an empty zip file or nothing happen but I still can compress a zip file which contains `test.txt` file.

Comment: That is correct.  You will need to implement your own substitute for `addRecursive` that skips files with the extensions you don't want.  `setStoreExtensions` will not help you.  AFAIK Poco::Zip does not have any built-in way to do exactly what you want.

Comment: @MilesBudnek appreciated a lot.

Comment: @MilesBudnek if you don't mind, can you help me answer this question also about Poco::Zip: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59560438/pocozip-compress-decompress